# Grub os-probe showing deleted Windows installation

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, grub2

I recently purchased a Dell Vostro notebook with Ubuntu Netbook edition 10.04 pre-installed. I tried adding a partition and installed Windows XP but it didn't work out due to too many partitions in the system already.

Now I have restored the laptop to factory setting using Dell Utility partition and the Windows partition is completely deleted, however my grub2 still shows Windows on /dev/sda2

> sudo os-probe
>
> Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda2)

Any ideas how to remove it from grub? I know I can remove /etc/grub.d/30_os-probe but I am more interested in why os-probe is showing the deleted partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities that I can think of:

- The Dell utility deleted the marking of the partition but left all the data intact, and did not expand your Ubuntu partition to fill the space, and thus os-prober is somehow picking up on the remains of the Windows partition.  That would indicate a bug in os-prober.
- The utility didn't even delete the partition, but rather just reinstalled the boot loader when it found your Ubuntu partition still present!  In that case, os-prober is actually correct.  Have you checked with gparted or the like to verify that the partition *is* actually gone?
- There is a restore partition there.  While GRUB shouldn't treat a restore partition as an actual Windows installation, I've heard of various distributions doing so before, most recently Fedora 13, so it's not out of the realm of possibility.  Very unlikely though, as your notebook came with Ubuntu pre-installed.

Comment: I have checked with gparted. The windows partition is deleted and there is no /dev/sda2 in the machine.

Comment: And is /dev/sda1 now encompassing the entire space of the drive?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Comment: That is very weird then; I think you have just found a bug in os-prober.  You could try reporting the bug to Ubuntu or GRUB upstream if you want.